# TPL Dataflow C# wait for all linked blocks to complete

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm using TPL Dataflow to build a pipeline. This pipeline should logically do the following:

1. Start by processing multiple data items - let's say it's `pollingBlock`.
2. In case certain conditions are met pass **one** of the items (that has met the conditions) to certain block for further monitoring, let's say it's `monitoringBlock`. Each `monitoringBlock` can hold only 1 item, but there are multiple `monitoringBlocks`.
3. `pollingBlock` should keep processing all the items including the one posted in a `while (true)` manner.
4. `monitoringBlocks` while occupied should not accept any other messages and these messages should just get deleted without further processing.
5. After some processing in `monitoringBlock` the message should either be marked as completed or transfer to the next block for processing, this next block is `processingBlock`

A brief sample:

```
public Task ExecutePipeline()
{
    var block = CreatePollingPipeline();
    block.Post((_serviceOne, _serviceTwo));

    block.Complete();
    return block.Completion;
}

public ActionBlock<(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)> CreatePollingPipeline()
{
    var pollingAlertHolder = new BufferBlock<(string input1, string input2)>();

    var pollingBlock = new ActionBlock<(IServiceOne serviceOne, IServiceTwo serviceTwo)>(services =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Posting to alert block");
            pollingAlertHolder.Post(("INP1", "INPVAL"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Posting to alert block");
            pollingAlertHolder.Post(("INP1", "INPVAL"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Posting to alert block");
            pollingAlertHolder.Post(("INP2", "INPVAL2"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Posting to alert block");
            pollingAlertHolder.Post(("INP1", "INPVAL"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Posting to alert block");
            pollingAlertHolder.Post(("INP1", "INPVAL"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Posting to alert block");
            pollingAlertHolder.Post(("INP2", "INPVAL2"));
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    });

    var monitoringBlock = new TransformBlock<(string input1, string input2), (string input1, string input2)>(inputs =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("monitoringBlock started");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("monitoringBlock completed");

            return (inputs.input1, inputs.input2);
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, BoundedCapacity = 1 });

    pollingAlertHolder.LinkTo(monitoringBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true },
        inputs => inputs.input1 == "INP1" && inputs.input2 == "INPVAL");
    pollingAlertHolder.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<(string input1, string input2)>());

    var processingBlock = new ActionBlock<(string input1, string input2)>(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("processingBlock started");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("processingBlock completed");
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, BoundedCapacity = 1 });
    monitoringBlock.LinkTo(processingBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });


    return pollingBlock;
}
```

My question is how do I keep `monitoringBlock` occupied until linked `processingBlock` finishes its' job? I don't want any items to be posted to `monitoringBlock` before the message finished the **FULL** processing cycle.

Comment: [Task.WaitAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1), [Task.WaitAny()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @RobertHarvey for that i'll need to expose the child blocks task which is not something i'd like to do, unless you suggest calling it internally? If yes then where exactly?

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of passing around Task objects.  They're designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: It seems to me that the `monitoringBlock` (2nd-stage) and the `processingBlock` (3nd-stage) should be combined to a single block. In other words all code currently located in the 3nd-stage should be transferred at the end of the 2nd-stage, and then the 3nd-stage could be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you can simply encapsulate logic of `monitoringBlock` and `processingBlock` in one block, for example, you can achieve that via predefined [`Datablock.Encapsulate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.encapsulate) method.

However, if you don't want to do that, you can use [`AutoResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent) or similar abstraction, and your code could be like this:

```
AutoResetEvent dataflowEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);
var bufferBlock = new ActionBLock<(string input1, string input2)>(i =>
{
    dataflowEvent.WaitOne();
    monitoringBlock.Post(i);
});
var monitoringBlock = new TransformBlock<(string input1, string input2), (string input1, string input2)>(inputs =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("monitoringBlock started");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("monitoringBlock completed");

        dataflowEvent.Set();
        return (inputs.input1, inputs.input2);
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, BoundedCapacity = 1 });
```